# Wordpress Edit Post Hook to load custom data

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an `meta_box` in the post creation screen. As soon a user click on a specific category it will be displayed. For saving the information in the `meta_box` and post title and post content I use the hook `post_updated`. All is going to save fine in the database -- post data in wp_posts and the data in the meta_box into a special created table.

But sometimes the user want to edit this post from this 'special 'category. In this case the `meta_box` with the inserted information should be loaded and be editable. I know that I need to fill in the fields manually, but I need to know which hook is called when the user presses the edit link. An idea was, check for the url and if a parameter edit is found call my edit routine. But it looks like a dirty thing for me.

The codex is not very helpful. I tried the following hooks:

> edit post, publish post, save post, wp insert post

But they are called after I pressed the actualize button.

BR,

mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use any hook for this, you just need to use following lines where you are generating your meta_box html

```
global $post;
```

now you have access the $post object when you are editing

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

use above function to get the value of particular meta and set it to your html as required.
for reading more about get_post_meta, goto http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: Hello makki, currently I don't use post meta, I store the box input in a separate table. I think I will/must use post meta in future ;-) THanks for your answer, this gets me on the right way now :)